# Sidebar menu tabs from html to jquery

Tags: jquery, html, menu

I want this code to include some jQuery so that when I press one tab on the sidebar menu it will show me the data for it in a container on the same page with out refreshing the page. I have tried ways to do it however none of them have worked for me.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <h3>Your Profile <h5> Landlord </5></h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="width:300px;">
     <li><a href="#">Personal Information</a></li> 
    <li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="landlord_profile.php"> My Properties <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="landlord_addproperty.php">Add a Property</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Edit your properties</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>

    <li><a href="#">Upload Profile Image</a></li>
    <li><a href="deactivate_myaccount.php">Deactivate My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">    Change Password </a></li>


  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>New Graph api & Javascript Base FBConnect Tutorial | Thinkdiff.net</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function call(page)
{
  $( "#result" ).load(page);
}
</script>
<div class="container-fluid" style="width:40%;float:left;">
<h3>Your Profile <h5> Landlord </5></h3>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="width:300px;">
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">Personal Information</a></li> 
<li> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');"> My Properties <span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">Add a Property</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">Edit your properties</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">Upload Profile Image</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">Deactivate My Account</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="call('test.html');">    Change Password </a></li>


  </ul>
</div>
<div id="result" style="width:60%;float:left;">sdsdsdsd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm provide here an example code that hope useful for you. test.html page contains only right side html

Comment: Thanks for the code. I have linked the pages to their respective tabs however when i press the tab it doesnt show in the box.

Comment: See what we are basically doing here, we just call a function on click of every tab with page name as a parameter. jQuery load function call that page and replace result id html code. So make sure you have insert request data to valid id. Either please share atleast pages code with me. so i can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not getting your full question but as what I understand its a problem with your linking a page from sidebar menu. If you post the side Menu code may be I will understand well.

Comment: Have a look with this link it might be helpful [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/)